# Need to Move label in .net application

Tags: c#, .net

I want to move the location of label vertically or horizontally and it should appear from in the windows form and should be invisible at a location by moving. I want to make it through .net application using c# so can any one help me for this?

Comment: What Will is trying to say (I'll assume that you don't want to spend your valuable time reading that long text) is that you should consider to spend a little more time writing your question. If you don't, why should we spend our time writing you a nice answer?

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that I just spent some of my valuable time reading that. That seems to imply malicious intent, which I highly doubt the asker has. Perhaps this is a more useful reference: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Buddy, you can use the property `Location`

```
MyLabel.Location.x = ??
MyLabel.Location.y = ??
```

Then hide it by using the property`Visible`

```
MyLabel.Visible = false`
```

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell exactly what you're trying to accomplish here. I'm going to assume that you want to move a label from its current position on the form to a new position while the application is running. I also assume that you want to make the label invisible while you're moving it so that you cannot see it move across the form.

You can do this easily by setting the [`Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location.aspx) property of the label you want to move to its new location. (If necessary, like if you want to move the label a relative number of pixels, you can get the label's *current* position from the `Location` property before you set it.) The label control also has a [`Visible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible.aspx) property that you can set to `True` or `False` to show/hide the control, respectively:

```
//Hide the label first
myLabel.Visible = false;

//Move the label to a new location on the form
myLabel.Location = new Point(30, 25);

//Make the label visible again
myLabel.Visible = true;
```

If I guessed wrong, and you're just trying to move the label during design-time (before you start running your program), you can just drag-and-drop it to a new position on the form.

Answer (score 0):

you just drag and drop

Answer (score 0):

You can make a label invisible by using the `Visible` Property.

```
myHiddenLabel.Visible = false;
```